# Creating website using Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have installed zend server on my local system.I created one project folder using this command line argument

```
zf create project quickstart
```

The project folder is created on C:\Program Files\Zend.
How i can run the project in browser.
http://localhost/zend/

Comment: More Information, for starters which Web Server do you use?

Comment: *(reference)* [Zend Framework Quickstart Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you create a simple zend framework with zend studio (it creates all necessary files).

put it in your server folder (htdocs) und run it with localhost/project/public/index.php

You don't need the zend server to build/run zend Projects.

Just Download mix or max Zend Framework package and you can start.

Comment: Thanks Fincha.But in my zend server folder their is no htdocs folder.

Comment: Do you have set up an vhost for some domain and the folder localhost/project/public/ ?

Comment: you can setup vhost but it ist not necessary, You have to setup vhost if you wonna for example zend.local run directly in your public folder, but it is for "advanced" zend user. if i create a zend project i get 3 folders library, application and public. the library contains zend folder, this is the framework, if this folder is empty you application will not work.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not to use a subfolder or you'll have problems with URLs. Create a virtual host on you local apache ! it's by far the best solution !

look here
http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/
download the PDF, at the end of page 3 there is the guide to configure the virtualhost

Briefly,
add this to apache conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName zf-tutorial.localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/zf-tutorial/public
<Directory "/var/www/html/zf-tutorial/public">
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

where 
/var/www/html/zf-tutorial/public
is the path to the index.php (inside public folder of the zend project)
If you are using windows, use c:/www/etc...

then edit hosts file (linux: /etc/hosts)
and add the line

```
127.1.0.1 zf-tutorial
```

restart apache and point the browser to

```
http://zf-tutorial
```